# Automatically nesting files in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I currently have a couple of batch scripts in one of my projects which run in a pre-build event which generate some new `.cs` files by calling `svcutil.exe` and `xsd.exe`.  I'd like to have these files automatically nested under their base file in the Solution Explorer.  I can handle manually needing to include them if necessary, if they'll be automatically nested after they are.

Is there any batch script, tool, or naming convention I can use to make Visual Studio automatically nest them?